# Vision Framework providing inexact roll and yaw values

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Vision Framework to try and get the roll and yaw of a face.

I'm using a `VNSequenceRequestHandler` on my `CVPixelBuffer` and am able to use both `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` and/or `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` to successfully get back the faces including landmarks (for the landmark request). So far so good.

However, when I try and get the `roll` and `yaw` values, I'm getting them as one a discrete set of values rather than a continuous range of values reflecting the exact orientation of the face.

The iOS docs for [roll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnfaceobservation/2980939-roll) and [yaw](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnfaceobservation/2980940-yaw) state that:

> The roll/yaw is reported in radians. A positive angle corresponds to counterclockwise roll. The range is [-Pi, Pi). A nil value indicates that the roll/yaw angle hasn't been computed.

However, when I look at the value, whilst `roll` is clearly being computed, I'm only getting discrete values, i.e. as my face rotates from right way up to upside-down, I get:

```
0 - face is upright

0.524 (Pi/6) - face starts rotating

1.047

1.571 (Pi/2) - face is now landscape

2.094

2.618

-3.142 (-Pi) - face is now upside-down
```

In other words, it seems there are only 12 possible roll values.

Surely this is not correct?

`yaw` is even worse, I only get `0.785` and `-0.785` in either direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple have now confirmed that this is in fact the designed behaviour: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113601

> The yaw and roll properties of a VNFaceObservation return a limited, discrete set of values, not a continuous range.
>
> If you would like a higher degree of precision in these values, you should file an enhancement request!